# Migrating EE to fresh install changed file upload directory ID - Now what?

Tags: wygwam

I am rebuilding a current site from scratch and I've rebuilt the file upload directories and migrated all of the previous uploads over but now, the path variable in my links references the upload directory ID of my previous installation. Before, it was...

```
{filedir_8}
```

and now, it's...

```
{filedir_2}
```

I am using WYGWAM v.2.7 and EE v.2.5.5. I am using CKFinder for the upload manager.

Any recommendations to correcting this? I know I could develop some sort of SQL query, but I am hoping there is another way.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to go into your new database and manually change the IDs of your upload directories in `exp_upload_prefs` to match your old site. Use phpMyAdmin to do this if it's installed on your server.

(This is assuming, of course, that you haven't made a bunch of new associations with the new directory ID since migrating.)

**UPDATE:** Alternately, you can do a find and replace on each Wygwam field via SQL:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data SET field_id_XX = REPLACE(field_id_XX,'filedir_8','filedir_2');
```

Do this for each Wygwam field, replacing `field_id_XX` with the actual `id` for that field.

Comment: Would there be a way to have the query JUST give me results from Wygwam fields?

I am kinda floored that there isn't a script that auto-runs to re-map these when you change the file upload directory in the Wygwam editor configuration?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question? My answer directly changes `{filedir_8}` so it points to your new directory (initally named `{filedir_2}`, now `{filedir_8}`.) Re: lack of remapping - I imagine that it's because you can link to file in any upload directory you like - just because you change directory for CK Finder doesn't mean that *all* your past uploads are in this new directory.

Comment: Just appended my answer with a query to find/replace the references in your fields.